# contando quantos dias faltam para terminar o ano

Tags: c++

Estava fazendo um programa em c++ para contar quantos dias faltam para terminar o ano a partir de uma data no formato dd/mm/yyyy mas de acordo com a data do mes que eu entro ele dá sempre o mesmo resultado tipo:

se eu digitar 18/02/2018 ou 12/02/2018 ele diz que faltam 340 dias ou se eu digitar 14/03/2018 ou 20/03/2017 ele mostra que faltam 275 dias. Por que ele esta fazendo isso?

o programa é este abaixo.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main ()
{
 int falta_dias = 0;
 int dia, mes, ano;
 int dias_mes[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

 do{
    printf("Digite uma data no formato dd/mm/yyyy: ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &dia, &mes, &ano);

    if(dia > 31 || dia < 1)printf("\n\tDia %d invalido.!!\n\tDigite um dia de 01 a 31\n",dia);

    if(mes > 12 || mes < 1)printf("\n\tMes %d invalido.!!\n\tDigite um mes de 01 a 12\n",mes);

   }while((dia > 31 || dia < 1) || (mes > 12 || mes < 1));

   dias_mes[1] = (ano%4 == 0 || ano%400 == 0 && ano%100 != 0) ? 29 : 28;

   for(int i = mes; i<12; i++)
   falta_dias += dias_mes[i];

   printf("\n\nFaltam %d dias para terminar o ano %04d.\n\n", falta_dias,ano);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sempre que colocar código nas suas perguntas formate-o com o botão de formatação da pergunta `{}` ou utilizando o atalho Ctrl+K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voce só está contando os dias a partir do próximo mes ao qual voce indica na entrada padrao (seu loop `for(int i = mes; i<12; i++)`).
Adicione os dias restantes no mes escolhido ao seu codigo:

```
for(int i = mes; i<12; i++)
falta_dias += dias_mes[i];

falta_dias+=dias_mes[mes-1] - dia; // conta os dias restantes do mes indicado na entrada padrão
printf("\n\nFaltam %d dias para terminar o ano %04d.\n\n", falta_dias,ano);
```